# When will omp thread pool get destructed

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I use openomp in my service for parallelizing my loop. But every time when a request came in, my service will create a brand new thread for it, and this thread will use omp to create a thread pool. Can I ask when this thread pool will be detructed?

```
void foo() {
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1)
  // Do something
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    threads.push_back(
      std::thread(foo);
    );
  }
  for (auto& thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
  }
}
```

In this pseudo code, I noticed that:

1. In the for loop, the thread num is 8 * x + 1(8 cores host, some 8 omp threads for each std::thread, and 1 main thread).
2. After the for loop, the thread num get back to 1, which means all omp thread pools get destructed.

This can be reproduced in this simple code, but for some more complex situation but similar use cases, I noticed the thread pools didn't get destructed after their parent thread finished. So it is hard for me to understand why.

So can I ask when the thread pool of omp will get destructed?

Comment: Afaik the openmp runtime manages the threads in some "smart" way, so it will not restart the threads every time, but it is not defined when this will happen.

Comment: Mixing OpenMP with std::thread, is not covered by the OpenMP specification and therefore the behavior is vendor-specific.  I suggest using either OpenMP or std::thread, but not both of them.

Comment: Please have a look at "Resource Relinquishing Routines" at https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpse36.html#x201-2340003.6.  They are meant to request a shutdown of the OpenMP runtime, which will include the OpenMP threads.

Comment: Just curious how you're evaluation that your OMP thread pools don't disappear.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Just check the threads num of this process by htop, ps, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The creation and deletion of the *native threads* of an OpenMP parallel region is left to the OpenMP implementation (eg. IOMP for ICC/Clang, GOMP for GCC) and is not defined by the [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-2.pdf). The specification do not restrict implementations to create native threads at the beginning of a parallel region nor to delete them at the end. In fact, most implementation keep the threads alive as long as possible because creating threads is slow (especially on many-core architectures). The specification explicitly mention the difference between native threads and basic OpenMP threads/tasks (everything is a task in OpenMP 5). Note that OMPT can be used to track when native threads are created and deleted. I expect mainstream implementation to create threads during the runtime initialization (typically when the first parallel section is encountered) and to delete threads when the program ends.

The specification states:

> [A native thread is] a thread defined by an underlying thread implementation 
> **If** the parallel region creates a native thread, a `native-thread-begin` event occurs as the first event in the context of the new thread prior to the `implicit-task-begin` event. 
> **If** a native thread is destroyed at the end of a parallel region, a `native-thread-end` event occurs in the thread as the last event prior to destruction of the thread.

Note that implementations typically destroy and recreate new threads when the number of threads of a parallel region is different from the previous one. This also happens in pathological cases like nesting.

The documentation of GOMP is available [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/) but it is not very detailed. The one of IOMP is available [here](https://openmp.llvm.org/) and is not much better... You can find interesting information directly in the code of the runtimes. For example, in the [GOMP code](https://www.cs.rice.edu/%7Ela5/doc/ligbomp-doc/de/d9b/team_8c-source.html). Note that there are useful comments like:

> We only allow the reuse of idle threads for non-nested PARALLEL regions

Comment: Is this any way to manually delete the OMP threads pool? Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, no, not standard OpenMP runtime function does that. That being said, specific runtime may provide such a function, but using such function will make your code dependent of a specific runtime which is generally a bad idea for the long run (due to bugs, performance, or portability issues with a given runtime). They may be some ugly way to cheat so for runtime to release the thread (like calling `omp_set_num_threads(1)`), but AFAIK no standard solution guarantee the pool to be released. This is generally not a problem since threads are not ready and so not scheduled.